# How would you draw multiple screens in PyGame (in only one window)?

Tags: python, pygame, game-engine

I'm trying to port over some code from Javascript to Python, and I'm having trouble even figuring out where to start. I've looked at a good dozen tutorials for PyGame, but none of them seem to click for me. So, I was hoping to get a quick example here, or at least a point in the right direction.

I'm wanting to make a number of screens I can switch back and forth between, depending on what the user is doing at the time, and even display two side by side. At the moment, all I've got is some Javascript that draws random circles onto the screen. The PyGame logic is the only thing I'm having trouble with.

[Here's my javascript for reference.](http://pastebin.com/mhj7FDUw)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Subsurface](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) for each subscreen that you want to create.

Then you may treat each as if it were a full screen / single surface, yet they still reference the original screen.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame is a wrapper for SDL. SDL uses a surface to represent a bitmap, or anything that can be drawn on screen. With the `pygame.display.set_mode((w,h),0,d)` you can get the surface, or the whole canvas. You can then draw or blit the other surfaces and then call `flip()`, to show changes. If you wish to have a few screens, you could have a current state number, and blit the screens accordingly. 
For example:

```
if(current_state == MAIN_SCREEN):
    drawAll(screen)
else
    drawEnemiesOnly(screen)
```

you could change the screens with the number keys:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEY_DOWN:
            if(event.key == K_1):
                current_state = 1
```